# I'm trying write some code that checks if specific text, the login details in my case, is in a file in python

Tags: python, if-statement, append

//this asked a fresh user for log in details and then appends it to the file

```
while choice == '1':
 username = input('enter a name: ')
 if username == '':
  print ('user name cant be blank')
 else:
  print ('hello', username,'welcome to the quiz')
  password = input('please enter a password that is 4 characters long: ')
   while (len(password)) < 4:
    password = input('please enter a password that is 4 characters long: ')
   else:
    f = open("logininfo", "a")
    f.write('---------'+'\n')
    f.write(username+'\n')
    f.write(password+'\n')
    f.write('---------'+'\n')
    f.close()
    print('welcome you may now begin')
    choice=choice+choice+choice
```

//this is for when a user wants to log in and the system checks in the file for already inputted data

```
while choice == '2':
 print ('enter your log in details')
 username = input('username:')
 password = input('password:')
 if username in logininfo:
  print ("That user already exsist")
 else:  
   f = open('logininfo','r')
   if username in ('logininfo'):
    print('welcome')
   else:
    print ('no entry')
```

Comment: i guess you want `if f"--\n{username}\n{password}\n--" in f.read()` ...

Comment: It would be simpler if you put the username and password on the same line, perhaps as a CSV. And of course you should be hashing the password.

Comment: you have use `f.read()` to get text from file. Evetually you can use `for`-loop with `f.readline()` to check line by line. But it would be much simpler if you would save it as `CSV` or `JSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
with open("logininfo", "r") as f:
    all_text = f.read()
```

Now find the username in the variable string 'all_text' with if statement

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help that works brilliant I just put it in and it all works great